# Java : How to Upload Image on my Windows Azure CDN?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cdn, azure-cdn

I'm using spring MVC to create my project webapp. what i want is how to upload images on my windows azure account CDN (Content Delivery Network)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b50e8ba6-9b08-4d52-b66e-11e81a85d6fb/android-how-to-upload-image-to-azure-storage-blob?forum=windowsazuredata#9f0b0bfe-48af-4c4f-823c-4417e5f17c01) is what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// You will need these imports

    import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobClient;
    import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer;
    import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlockBlob;
    import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.CloudStorageAccount;

// Initialize Account

    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse([ACCOUNT_STRING]);

// Create the blob client

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Create or overwrite the "myimage.jpg" blob with contents from a local
// file
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("myimage.jpg");
File source = new File("c:\\myimages\\myimage.jpg");
blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());

Source : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/03/05/windows-azure-storage-client-for-java-overview.aspx
```